WP_User_Query get_count issue with meta_query relation
I'm using WP_User_Query to count the total number of users based on specific criteria. Generally, the following code works well:
$args = [/* your arguments here */];
$query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$total = $query->get_total();

However, I encounter an issue when using a meta_query with a relation set to 'OR'. Here’s an example:
$args = [
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR', // No matter the value here
        // other meta query clauses
    ],
    // other arguments
];

In this case, the get_total() method returns zero.
The only way I have found to get the total is by using:
$total = count($query->get_results());

Am I the only one experiencing this issue?
Is there a workaround to get get_total() to work correctly when meta_query relation is set?
